# SQL query does a join only if table is not empty

Tags: sql, join

What I want to achieve is that I have a TABLE A and TABLE B they are both using same IDs, but some of the IDs in A do not exist in B and as such if I am looking for that specific ID and have a join I don't get out anything.

My query is like this

```
        SELECT *
        FROM table_A A
        LEFT JOIN table_B B
        ON A.id = B.id
        WHERE B.condition <> "X"
        AND A.id = "Y"
```

If I select and ID that exists in both A and B it works, but not if it only exists in A, so how could I get out results even if the row is not in table B?

Comment: On a side note: String literals should be enclosed in single quotes (e.g. `'Y'`) in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the table_B condition to the `ON` clause to get `LEFT JOIN` result instead of `INNER JOIN` result.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_A A
LEFT JOIN table_B B
  ON A.id = B.id
 AND B.condition <> "X"
WHERE A.id = "Y"
```

Comment: Thank you, that did exactly what I needed it to do.